# .net - vb.net Horizontal Scroll Bar on DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dd

I have a DataGridView on a Windows Form that can have up to 25 columns and up to many thousands of rows. There are no defined columns in the DGV, these are dynamically generated in the code.  No columns are frozen.  The DGV works as expected in the version I inherited.  Then I got my hands on it…

I am adding a toolbar to the form.  The issue I am facing is that when I lower the top of the DGV to fit just below the toolbar and ensure the DGV fits on the form, I lose my horizontal scroll bar.  I can scroll the thumb off the form, so it is no longer visible.  My Document Count field shows as expected in the image below.

[DGV no horizontal bar and thumb scrolled off form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZIyU.png)

Some potentially related field values from DGV Properties:

- AutoSizeColumnsMode = None
- AutoSizeRowsMode = None
- Dock = None
- ScrollBars = Both

Any input would be much appreciated.

Added a Screen Shot to help clarify the issue.

[Design View of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqgVy.png)

Comment: The bottom of the grid looks like it's behind the tool strip.  Try Dock = Fill on your grid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply@LarsTech but that filled the whole screen with my grid.  Tried Dock = Right and it is closer to what i want, but then my toolbar and document count are left of the grid.

Comment: I can only go by what you showed in that image.  Resize the grid the way you want then set the Anchor property to all sides.

Comment: @LarsTech - I added a screenshot of my design view.  I tried Anchoring all sides and had the same issue.

Comment: Is the grid inside a panel?  If so, then the panel needs to be anchored too.

Comment: @LarsTech I'm not sure.  There isn't anything in the Form Design. However, the DGV is double buffered for faster loading and smoother scrolling.  Is that related?  Getting to the limits of my vb.net/visual studio knowledge.  I should have mentioned in my original post that i am relatively new to vb.net/visual studio, but am an old programmer.

Comment: Your first image clearly shows the grid extending beyond the bottom of the form.  You can see the up arrow of the vertical scroll bar, but you don't see the down arrow because it's below or hidden by the status strip.  It's clearly an anchoring problem, whether it's on the grid or a parent container, I can't tell from just the screen shots.  It looks like you have the anchoring correct, but you might be re-sizing the grid yourself in code somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, @LarsTech.  I need to take a much closer look at the code.  I will post here once i find the solution.

Comment: If you are using the designer; Try removing the grid and putting in a new one. It's a know bug that sometimes the `Dockmode` `Fill` has troubles with `DataGridViews`. It solved it for me last time.

Comment: @Luke Next time, just play with the BringToFront or SendToBack methods of the control to resolve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!  Thanks @Luke @LarsTech for suggestions.  Not sure why but recreating it solved the horizontal scroll bar issue. I deleted my grid and recreated it in the Designer just like the previous one. This time I used Dock Right instead of None or Fill. I did use BringToFront also, because SendToBack shrunk my toolbar to half the size. I lost my blank area on the right of the grid, but i can live with that.

Thank you so much for the help!